# Appropriate term for "seemingly unrelated regression with shared parameters"?

Tags: regression, bias, parameterization, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I have paired values for three variables $z$, $y$, and $t$, and I wish the perform the regressions $z = g(t)$ and $y = f(t)$. I happen to know there is a bias in the variable $t$, thus the true times could be written as $t^* := t + \tau$ where $\tau$ is some shift in the domain of $g$ and $f$.

Thus my regression equations in structural form will be

$$y = f(t + \tau)$$
$$z = g(t + \tau)$$

where $\tau$ is treated as a trainable parameter.

It might help my literature review if I knew what this approach to bias correction was conventionally called. The two equations 'could' be trained separately, so would I call this *seemingly unrelated regression*? Or does the shared parameter lend itself to a different term?

Otherwise I intend to term this *seemingly unrelated regression with shared parameters* (SUR-SP).

Comment: Or [random effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_effects_model)?